# How to make a function to return really different types in fsharp?

Tags: types, f#, overloading, return-type

Assume that there is a third-party library written in FSharp, it contains several generic classes, for example as follows:

- type **FirstType<'a>**

  has method **DoWork**, that accepts:

  - first param of type **FirstType<'a>**,
  - second param is a function of type ('a -> 'b)

  **DoWork** method return type is **FirstType<'b>**
- type **SecondType<'a>**

  has method **DoWork**, that accepts:

  - first param of type **SecondType<'a>**,
  - second param is a function of type ('a -> 'b)

  **DoWork** method return type is **SecondType<'b>**
- type **ThirdType**<'a>

  has method **DoWork**, that accepts:

  - first param of type **ThirdType**<'a>,
  - second param is a function of type ('a -> 'b)

  **DoWork** method return type is **ThirdType<'b>**

These classes have no common interfaces or parent classes, type Object is their only common parent.

Each of the types below has one method named **DoWork**. It accepts two parameters:

- the first has the type of the class containing DoWork method
- the second is a function (it accepts param of type equal to generic param of the class and returns element of any type, call it 'b)

Then this DoWork function should return the object which has type of the class it is situated in, but with generic type parameter equal to 'b.

**Currently. Example usage of these classes:**

```
let first = new FirstType<int>()
...
// here result is of type FirstType<string>
let result = FirstType.DoWork first (fun x -> "hello" + x.toString())

let second = new SecondType<int>()
...
// here result is of type SecondType<bool>
let result = SecondType.DoWork second (fun x -> 2 = 4)

let third = new ThirdType<string>()
...
// here result is of type ThirdType<int>
let result = ThirdType.DoWork third (fun x -> x.Length())
```

**The Problem:**

It is required to implement a function called **Do**, that accepts two parameters, first - an object that has type either equal to FirstType<'a> or to SecondType<'a> or to ThirdType<'a>, second - a function of type ('a -> 'b) where 'b can be a type another from 'a. So, this function should determine the type of it's first input parameter and based on this - return appropriate type.

The return type of **Do** function:

- should be an object of type FirstType<'b> if the first param of Do function was of type FirstType<'a>
- should be an object of type SecondType<'b> if the first param of Do function was of type SecondType<'a>
- should be an object of type ThirdType<'b> if the first param of Do function was of type ThirdType<'a>

**Desired. Example usage of these classes:**

```
let first = new FirstType<int>()
let second = new SecondType<int>()
let third = new ThirdType<string>()
...
// here result1 should be of type FirstType<string>
let result1 = Do first (fun x -> "hello" + x.toString())

// here result2 should be of type SecondType<bool>
let result2 = Do second (fun x -> 2 = 4)

// here result3 should be of type ThirdType<int>
let result3 = Do third (fun x -> x.Length())
```

I have thought of function overloading, but it is not allowed to be used in F#. I am now thinking of how to make a function return really different types, not Discriminated Unions, because at the point of calling the function it expects a specific type.

**UPDATE:**

I have looked at the comment of John Palmer and tried it.

```
type Ops =
    static member Do (f: 'a -> 'b) (x:FirstType<'a>) = ...
    static member Do (f: 'a -> 'b) (x:SecondType<'a>) = ...
    static member Do (f: 'a -> 'b) (x:ThirdType<'a>) = ...
```

When trying to create a function:

```
let Do f x = Ops.Do f x
```

There is the following error:

> Error:    One or more of the overloads of this method has curried arguments. Consider redesigning these members to take arguments in tupled form.

The same error is when trying to use this **Do** function as a member of class Ops:

```
let result1 = first |> Ops.Do(fun x -> x + 2)
let result2 = second |> Ops.Do(fun x -> "hello" + x.ToString())
let result3 = third |> Ops.Do(fun x -> x = 1) sq
```

When redesigning Do methods in Ops type with arguments in tupled form and creating Do function like this:

```
let Do f x = Ops.Do (f, x)
```

.. there is the following error in the Error List:

> Error:        A unique overload for method 'Do' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed. Candidates: static member Ops.Do: f:('a -> 'b) * x:FirstType<'a> -> FirstType<'b>, static member Ops.Do: f:('a -> 'b) * x:SecondType<'a> -> SecondType<'b>, static member Ops.Do : f:('a -> 'b) * x:ThirdType<'a> -> ThirdType<'b>

So, I am able to use **Do** only with indicating a class name (Ops) and in a tupled form.. as I have understood with the help of error messages.

**Is there any way to be able to use currying with overloaded member-methods?**

The usage I am dreaming of is like this:

```
let result = input |> Do someFunction
```

I would be happy if someone has any ideas or suggestions. Maybe I am wrong at some point.

Comment: F# does support function overloading of member functions - I think that would be the answer

Comment: @JohnPalmer thank you for comment, I have tried to use member-functions with overloading and updated my question. Is it possible to use currying with such methods? Or any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @JohnPalmer I looked more carefully to my code and managed to do what I wanted by inline functions. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
type FirstType<'a>  = FirstType  of 'a
type SecondType<'a> = SecondType of 'a
type ThirdType<'a>  = ThirdType  of 'a   

type Ops = Ops with
    static member ($) (Ops, FirstType  a) = fun f -> FirstType  (f a)
    static member ($) (Ops, SecondType a) = fun f -> SecondType (f a)
    static member ($) (Ops, ThirdType  a) = fun f -> ThirdType  (f a)

let inline Do f x = (Ops $ f) x

let first  = FirstType  10
let second = SecondType 12
let third  = ThirdType  "Hello"

let result1 = Do first  (fun x -> "hello" + x.ToString())
let result2 = Do second (fun x -> 2 = 4)
let result3 = Do third  (fun x -> x.Length)
```

Find more about inline and overloading in [these posts](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net//). It seems you are trying to implement a generic map function over your wrapper classes, this correspond to the [Functor Typeclass in Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids), which has a function `fmap`, with the same signature as your `Do` function but with the arguments flipped.