# Returning arrays of different dimensions from one function; is it possible in F#?

Tags: arrays, f#

I am trying to convert some Python to F#, specifically [numpy.random.randn](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html).

The function takes a variable number of int arguments and returns arrays of different dimensions based on the number of arguments.

I believe that this is not possible because one cannot have a function that returns different types (`int[]`, `int[][]`, `int[][][]`, etc.) unless they are part of a discriminated union, but want to be sure before committing to a workaround.

The sanity check:

```
member self.differntarrays ([<ParamArray>] dimensions: Object[]) =
    match dimensions with
    | [| dim1 |] ->      
         [| 
            1 
         |]
    | [| dim1; dim2 |] -> 
        [|
           [| 2 |], 
           [| 3 |] 
        |]
    | _ -> failwith "error"
```

causes error:

```
This expression was expected to have type  
    int    
but here has type  
    'a * 'b
```

with the `expression` being : `[| 2 |], [| 3 |]`
and the `int` referring to the 1 in `[| 1 |]`
i.e. the type of `1` is not the same as the type of `[| 2 |], [| 3 |]`

TLDR;

[numpy.random.randn](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)

> numpy.random.randn(d0, d1, ..., dn)
>
> Return a sample (or samples) from the “standard normal” distribution.
>
> If positive, int_like or int-convertible arguments are provided, randn
>   generates an array of shape (d0, d1, ..., dn), filled with random
>   floats sampled from a univariate “normal” (Gaussian) distribution of
>   mean 0 and variance 1 (if any of the d_i are floats, they are first
>   converted to integers by truncation). A single float randomly sampled
>   from the distribution is returned if no argument is provided.

Examples from interactive python session:

```
np.random.randn(1)  - array([-0.28613356])
np.random.randn(2)  - array([-1.7390449 ,  1.03585894]) 
np.random.randn(1,1)- array([[ 0.04090027]])
np.random.randn(2,3)- array([[-0.16891324,  1.05519898, 0.91673992],  
                             [ 0.86297031,  0.68029926, -1.0323683 ]])
```

The code is for [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/index.html) and since the values need to mutable for performance reasons, using immutable list is not an option.

Comment: You would need to use a DU

Comment: Might have a different workaround than DU: member self.differntarrays ([<ParamArray>] dimensions: Object[]) : Object[]  --   Notice it returns Object[]. This might cause problems downstream, so not committed yet.

Comment: Of note: [How to make a function to return really different types in fsharp?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24218051/1243762)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct - an array of floats `float[]` is a different type than array of arrays of floats
`float[][]` or 2D array of floats `float[,]` and so you cannot write a function that returns one or the other depending on the input argument.

If you wanted to do something like the Python's `rand`, you could write an overloaded method:

```
type Random() = 
  static let rnd = System.Random()
  static member Rand(n) = [| for i in 1 .. n -> rnd.NextDouble() |]
  static member Rand(n1, n2) = [| for i in 1 .. n1 -> Random.Rand(n2) |]
  static member Rand(n1, n2, n3) = [| for i in 1 .. n1 -> Random.Rand(n2, n3) |]
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Tomas' suggestion to use overloading is probably best, .NET arrays do share a common sub-type: `System.Array`. So what you want is possible.

```
member self.differntarrays ([<ParamArray>] dimensions: Object[]) : Array =
    match dimensions with
    | [| dim1 |] ->      
         [| 
            1 
         |] :> _
    | [| dim1; dim2 |] -> 
        [|
           [| 2 |], 
           [| 3 |] 
        |] :> _
    | _ -> failwith "error"
```

Comment: Thanks. I always appreciate a different answer as it leads to ideas for future problems and keeps the mind working.